# LibreOffice documents spill over into workplace below

Tags: libreoffice

I have LibreOffice 3.6.2.2
My problem is that documents sometimes (not always, it seems to be random) spill over into workplace below. The typing area is all on the screen, but the bottom part of the frame which shows what page I'm on etc. is off the screen and I find it when I go down to the workplace below. And the line that contains the Find box is completely lost in the middle somewhere.